# R: how to change the color of a point on a graph

Tags: r, plot, graph, data-visualization

I created a graph network with the following data:

#relationship data

```
Data_I_Have <- data.frame(
   
    "Node_A" = c("John", "John", "John", "Peter", "Peter", "Peter", "Tim", "Kevin", "Adam", "Adam", "Xavier"),
    "Node_B" = c("Claude", "Peter", "Tim", "Tim", "Claude", "Henry", "Kevin", "Claude", "Tim", "Henry", "Claude"),
    " Place_Where_They_Met" = c("Chicago", "Boston", "Seattle", "Boston", "Paris", "Paris", "Chicago", "London", "Chicago", "London", "Paris"),
  "Years_They_Have_Known_Each_Other" = c("10", "10", "1", "5", "2", "8", "7", "10", "3", "3", "5"),
  "What_They_Have_In_Common" = c("Sports", "Movies", "Computers", "Computers", "Video Games", "Sports", "Movies", "Computers", "Sports", "Sports", "Video Games")
)
```

#data about individuals

```
additional_data_about_people <- data.frame(
   
    "Person" = c("John", "Peter", "Tim", "Kevin", "Adam", "Xacier", "Claude", "Henry"),
   "Job" = c("Teacher", "Lawyer", "Accountant", "Engineer", "Teacher", "Lawyer", "Engineer", "Lawyer"),
"Age" = c("50", "51", "61", "56", "65", "65", "54", "50"),
"Favorite_Food" = c("pizza", "pizza", "tacos", "pizza", "ice cream", "sushi", "sushi", "pizza")
)


library(igraph)
library(dplyr)
library(visNetwork)


graph_file <- data.frame(Data_I_Have$Node_A, Data_I_Have$Node_B)


colnames(graph_file) <- c("Data_I_Have$Node_A", "Data_I_Have$Node_B")

graph <- graph.data.frame(graph_file, directed=F)
graph <- simplify(graph)

plot(graph)

nodes <- data.frame(id = V(graph)$name, title = V(graph)$name)
nodes <- nodes[order(nodes$id, decreasing = F),]
edges <- get.data.frame(graph, what="edges")[1:2]

visNetwork(nodes, edges) %>%   visIgraphLayout(layout = "layout_with_fr") %>%
    visOptions(highlightNearest = TRUE, nodesIdSelection = TRUE)
```

Within the visnetwork, does anyone know how I could change the color of "John" to red?

I know how to do this in igraph:

```
V(graph)["John"]$color<-"red"
```

But does anyone know how to do this in visnetwork?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `color` column to the nodes:

```
nodes <- data.frame(id = V(graph)$name, title = V(graph)$name)
nodes <- nodes[order(nodes$id, decreasing = F),]

John_ind <- which(nodes$id == "John")
colours <- rep("lightblue", nrow(nodes)); colours[John_ind] <- "red"
nodes <- cbind(nodes, color = colours)
edges <- get.data.frame(graph, what="edges")[1:2]

visNetwork(nodes, edges) %>%   visIgraphLayout(layout = "layout_with_fr") %>%
  visOptions(highlightNearest = TRUE, nodesIdSelection = TRUE)
```

You can customise your own colours accordingly.
[image]

### EDIT

For your comment, you have mistyped a name (Xavier) and you should be careful with the capitalisation of the `color` column. We can use `merge()` or `left_join` from dplyr package to merge the dataframes based on columns. I changed your DF column name to `id` for the names, so that they can match.

```
nodes <- data.frame(id = V(graph)$name, title = V(graph)$name)
nodes <- nodes[order(nodes$id, decreasing = F),]

colors = data.frame( "id" = c("John", "Peter", "Tim", "Kevin", "Adam", "Xavier", "Claude", "Henry"), 
                     "color" = c("red", "blue", "green", "black", "red", "blue", "black", "blue") )

nodes <- merge(nodes, colors, by = "id")
edges <- get.data.frame(graph, what="edges")[1:2]

visNetwork(nodes, edges) %>%   visIgraphLayout(layout = "layout_with_fr") %>%
  visOptions(highlightNearest = TRUE, nodesIdSelection = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much! But suppose now there is a whole data frame that has colors for each person. is there a quick way to add these colors to the visnetwork? e.g. 


 colors = data.frame(
    
    "Person" = c("John", "Peter", "Tim", "Kevin", "Adam", "Xacier", "Claude", "Henry"),
    "Color" = c("red", "blue", "green", "black", "red", "blue", "black", "blue")
    
)

Comment: @Noob I have added some code. Be careful of typos! And if this answers your questions, make sure to accept it (:

Comment: I figured out how to "select  by color"


nodes$color = colors$color

visNetwork(nodes, edges,  main = "test", width = "100%") %>%   visIgraphLayout(layout = "layout_with_fr") %>%
    visOptions(highlightNearest = TRUE, nodesIdSelection = TRUE) %>% visOptions(selectedBy = "colors$color") 

Is it possible to somehow have two selection bars? one for color and for id? Thank you for all your help!

Comment: @Noob maybe you can find your answer in the documentation: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/visNetwork/versions/2.0.9/topics/visOptions . It is good practice to try and see if you can understand the details mentioned in package documentations. If you still have trouble, you might want to start a new question as I cannot reproduce a result based on your code.

Comment: thank you for the help and your idea. I have started reading the documentation. in the mean time, I have made a new question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64978594/r-select-by-color-and-by-id