# R: select by color and by ID

Tags: r, graph, data-visualization, nodes, edges

I have the following data in R

```
Data_I_Have <- data.frame(
   
    "Node_A" = c("John", "John", "John", "Peter", "Peter", "Peter", "Tim", "Kevin", "Adam", "Adam", "Xavier"),
    "Node_B" = c("Claude", "Peter", "Tim", "Tim", "Claude", "Henry", "Kevin", "Claude", "Tim", "Henry", "Claude"),
    " Place_Where_They_Met" = c("Chicago", "Boston", "Seattle", "Boston", "Paris", "Paris", "Chicago", "London", "Chicago", "London", "Paris"),
  "Years_They_Have_Known_Each_Other" = c("10", "10", "1", "5", "2", "8", "7", "10", "3", "3", "5"),
  "What_They_Have_In_Common" = c("Sports", "Movies", "Computers", "Computers", "Video Games", "Sports", "Movies", "Computers", "Sports", "Sports", "Video Games")
)

additional_data_about_people <- data.frame(
   
    "Person" = c("John", "Peter", "Tim", "Kevin", "Adam", "Xacier", "Claude", "Henry"),
   "Job" = c("Teacher", "Lawyer", "Accountant", "Engineer", "Teacher", "Lawyer", "Engineer", "Lawyer"),
"Age" = c("50", "51", "61", "56", "65", "65", "54", "50"),
"Favorite_Food" = c("pizza", "pizza", "tacos", "pizza", "ice cream", "sushi", "sushi", "pizza")
)
```

Using this information, I created an interactive graph where you can "select by ID"

```
library(igraph)
library(dplyr)
library(visNetwork)


graph_file <- data.frame(Data_I_Have$Node_A, Data_I_Have$Node_B)


colnames(graph_file) <- c("Data_I_Have$Node_A", "Data_I_Have$Node_B")

graph <- graph.data.frame(graph_file, directed=F)
graph <- simplify(graph)


nodes <- data.frame(id = V(graph)$name, title = V(graph)$name)
nodes <- nodes[order(nodes$id, decreasing = F),]

colors = data.frame( "id" = c("John", "Peter", "Tim", "Kevin", "Adam", "Xavier", "Claude", "Henry"), 
                     "color" = c("red", "blue", "green", "black", "red", "blue", "black", "blue") )

nodes <- merge(nodes, colors, by = "id")
edges <- get.data.frame(graph, what="edges")[1:2]

visNetwork(nodes, edges) %>%   visIgraphLayout(layout = "layout_with_fr") %>%
  visOptions(highlightNearest = TRUE, nodesIdSelection = TRUE)
```

The code can be modified so that you can select by "color" instead of by "id":

```
 nodes$color = colors$color
 nodes <- data.frame(id = V(graph)$name, title = V(graph)$name)
 nodes <- nodes[order(nodes$id, decreasing = F),]
 
 colors = data.frame( "id" = c("John", "Peter", "Tim", "Kevin", "Adam", "Xavier", "Claude", "Henry"), 
                      "color" = c("red", "blue", "green", "black", "red", "blue", "black", "blue") )
 
 nodes <- merge(nodes, colors, by = "id")
 edges <- get.data.frame(graph, what="edges")[1:2]
 
 visNetwork(nodes, edges,  main = "A really simple example", width = "100%") %>%   visIgraphLayout(layout = "layout_with_fr") %>%
     visOptions(highlightNearest = TRUE, nodesIdSelection = TRUE) %>% visOptions(selectedBy = "color")
```

Is there a way to combine both of these together? Can you have two search bars, one for ID and one for color?

```
    visNetwork(nodes, edges,  main = "A really simple example", width = "100%") %>%   visIgraphLayout(layout = "layout_with_fr") %>%
     visOptions(highlightNearest = TRUE, nodesIdSelection = TRUE) %>% visOptions(selectedBy = "color") 

visNetwork(nodes, edges,  main = "A really simple example", width = "100%") %>%   visIgraphLayout(layout = "layout_with_fr") %>%
    visOptions(highlightNearest = TRUE, nodesIdSelection = TRUE) %>%
    visLegend()
```

Something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLAY6.jpg

Thanks

Comment: Did you see [this](https://datastorm-open.github.io/visNetwork/legend.html)?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't solve the problem unfortunately

Comment: @Noob did you run this code yourself? I am getting the error: 'In visOptions(., selectedBy = "colors$color") :
  Can't find 'colors$color' in node data.frame'.

Comment: @PLY :  sorry about that, there was a mistake. I think I fixed it now. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the last part of your code to

```
visNetwork(nodes, edges, main = "test", width = "100%") %>% 
  visIgraphLayout(layout = "layout_with_fr") %>% 
  visOptions(highlightNearest = TRUE, nodesIdSelection = TRUE,
             selectedBy = list(multiple = TRUE, variable = "color"))
```

It results in
[image]
If you want to add a legend, perhaps you should reconfigure your dataframe and check the link that @Daman deep commented.

Comment: thank you! is it possible to add a third drop down menu?

Comment: d = data.frame( "id" = c("John", "Peter", "Tim", "Kevin", "Adam", "Xavier", "Claude", "Henry"), 
                      "color" = c("r", "b", "g", "b", "r", "b", "b", "b") )


nodes <- merge(nodes, colors, by = "id")
nodesm<- merge(nodes, d, by = "id")
 edges <- get.data.frame(graph, what="edges")[1:2]
 
 visNetwork(nodesm, edges) %>%   visIgraphLayout(layout = "layout_with_fr") %>%
     visOptions(highlightNearest = TRUE, nodesIdSelection = TRUE) %>%  visOptions(highlightNearest = TRUE, nodesIdSelection = TRUE,
             selectedBy = list(multiple = TRUE, variable = "color"))